# Rewrite input lines for variable fields in AWK

Tags: awk

I want to rewrite the following lines (given sample of 3 lines, but it runs for about 500 lines)

```
sl_no, id, value1, value2, value3, total, invalid, no_option, gross_total
1,1,570,0,0,.......,655,0,1,656 
2,2,394,5,24,......,477,0,4,481 
3,3,489,9,2,.......,704,0,2,706
```

as

```
sl_no, id, 0, no_option
sl_no, id,loop, value1
sl_no, id,loop, value2
sl_no, id,loop, value3
```

i.e.

```
   1,1,0,1 
   1,1,1,570 
   1,1,2,0 
   1,1,3,0 
   2,2,0,4
   2,2,1,394 
   2,2,2,5 
   2,2,3,24 
   3,3,0,2 
   3,3,1,489 
   3,3,2,9 
   3,3,3,2
```

value_1 to value_3 is variable i.e. it can be value_1 to value_15 or it can be value_1 to value_8 or so

I tried with AWK but hard coding of variable value list is not manageable

```
$ awk -F, '{printf("%d,%s,0,%d\n%d,%s,1,%d\n%d,%s,2,%d\n%d,%s,3,%d\n",$1,$2,$(NF-1),$1,$2,$3,$1,$2,$4,$1,$2,$5)}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts in form of code. Please add Logic of getting your expected output in your question which will make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: This really isn't clear. Can you provide a shorter example and instead explain in more detail how the input corresponds to the expected output?

Comment: @canabadyweb: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to edit your question for adding clarity rather than saying "Basically the output should be code, sl_no, id, loop, value_1 code, sl_no, id, loop, value_2 code, sl_no, id, loop, value_3 ------ ____ code, sl_no, id, loop, value_12" inside of a comment. We would like to help you, but your question is absolutely not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `for` loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     { i=0; print $1,$2,i,$(NF-1) }
     { for(i=3; i<NF-4; i++){ print $1,$2,i-2,$i } }' file
```

Output:

```
1,1,0,1
1,1,1,570
1,1,2,0
1,1,3,0
2,2,0,4
2,2,1,394
2,2,2,5
2,2,3,24
3,3,0,2
3,3,1,489
3,3,2,9
3,3,3,2
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: You code too works as expected but with two correction viz, -F,  argument for awk  and for loop condition till <= i.e for(i=3; i<=NF-4; i++)

Answer (score 1):

Awk is a programming language, you can just loop over the fields.

Assuming the last four are fixed, you want to loop from the third through the fourth last.

```sh
awk -F , '{ printf "%i,%i,%i,%i\n", $1, $2, 0, $(NF-1)
  for(i=3; i<NF-4; ++i)
    printf "%i,%i,%i,%i\n", $1, $2, i-2, $i }' input.txt >output.txt
```